# how to check and assign the value to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code,

```
var point={
         'y':200,
         'name':'service'
};
var val = "point.y";
```

i need to check whether **val** is  exist if exist need to set the value as 250 instead of 200 through val..

how to achieve?

can you please solve

Comment: `point.hasOwnProperty('y') && (point.y = 250);` Which means `if(point.hasOwnProperty('y')) { point.y = 250; }`

Comment: you can use as @A.Wolff commented or you can use  var val = (point.y !== undefined)? 250 : 0 ; http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/ayd2o1pc/

Comment: Now rereading your question, what is you expected behaviour? Using a string to 'eval' it as object property or what? Maybe you want instead: `var val = "y";
point.hasOwnProperty(val) && (point[val] = 250);`

Comment: @A.Wolff working fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (point.hasOwnProperty(val) && point[val])
     point[val] = 250;
```

it's working

Comment: Your code would fail for `var point={
         'y':0,
         'name':'service'
};` Use only: `if (point.hasOwnProperty(val))` :)